# logic to determine if two time periods overlap (including overnight cases)

Tags: datetime, math, logic

Need help on the logic to determine if two time periods overlap

Assumption:

1. Time period is less than 24 hours
2. If end time is less than start time, it is an overnight period
3. The boundaries of time period are not inclusive (ie. `06:00-07:00` does not overlap with `07:00-08:00` nor `05:00-06:00`)

Example:
`A = (07:00-17:00)`
`P = (12:00-22:00)`
`N = (22:00-08:00) (overnight)`

What is the logic to determine if any given time period overlaps with A, P or N

Comment: So `11:00-11:00` is 0 hours (not 24 hours)? Does it overlap with `10:00-12:00`?

Comment: max 23hr59min (11:00-10:59) and min 1 min (00:00-00:01)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to reveal fact of intersection is dividing overnights into pairs of intervals, so

`N = (22:00-08:00)` becomes `N1 = (22:00-24:00)` and `N2 = (00:00-08:00)`

After that make simple interval intersection:

```
if (C.Start >= N1.End or C.End <= N1.Start) and (C.Start >= N2.End or C.End <= N2.Start):
       no intersection
second comparison if C consists of two intervals too
```

It seems that " not inclusive " boundaries don't influence onto comparison correctness

There are special methods for angular intervals, but using them here looks like overcomplication.

Comment: Can you explain the detail of logic on the necessary checks in terms of start time and end time?

Comment: Corrected erroneous conditions